# Files.list parallel runs on the same thread

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code which loops through files in a directory. The directory contains 3 files.

### Expected output

I expect the output to contain the names of different threads, since I use `parallel` on the stream. But instead it only displays one thread name for each file in the directory.

### Code

```java
package Concurrency;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class SandBox 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Files.list(Path.of("/Users/x/Desktop/targets")).parallel().forEach(new Consumer<Path>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Path path) {
                    System.out.println("From thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
From thread main
From thread main
From thread main
```

Comment: It depends on your environment, but you'll usually need a bigger stream for parallel processing to kick in.

Comment: Reading a directory listing depends on the file system, which usually has no parallel processing, printing to `System.out` has an internal synchronization, hence no benefit from parallel processing and you have just three files. Where does the expectation to witness parallel processing come from?

Comment: @Holger what do you mean? I don't expect the file system to be processed in parallel. You have any experience with java at all? I expect the consumer to be run in parallel, since I called parallel() on the Stream object. Have a look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't looking at big enough directories. Change your program to count up the threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path dir = Path.of(args[0]);

    var threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,AtomicInteger>();

    try(var stream = Files.list(dir)) {
        stream
        .parallel()
        //.peek(p -> System.out.println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+p))
        .forEach(p -> threads.computeIfAbsent(Thread.currentThread().getName(), tn -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet());
    }

    System.out.println("Number of files: " + threads.values().stream().mapToInt(AtomicInteger::get).sum());
    System.out.println("Threads used: " + threads.size() +" => "+threads);
}
```

Run on a small directory:

```
Number of files: 27
Threads used: 1 => {main=27}
```

Example from a big directory:

```
Number of files: 4025
Threads used: 2 => {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1=1977, main=2048}
```